# Sphinx multi toctree hierarchy of sub sub pages

Tags: python-sphinx, myst

I have the following page structure:

```
index.md
a/a.md
a/a/a.md
```

I am using `a` here for simplifying the example. I get a "duplicated label" warning now.
This happens also, when renaming.

`index.md` has the following content:

````
# namespace/project-name

## Table of Contents
```{toctree}

a/a
```
````

`a/a.md` has the following content:

````
```{toctree}

a/a
```
````

Once I do an html build with Sphinx, I get:
[image: a1 is a/a/a.md and a2 is a/a.md]

I wish for a1 being grouped underneath a2:
a > a

How can I achieve this?

Additional info:

- This is not a problem with MyST-parser, because this also happens with reST for me.
- I tried setting `:maxdepth: X` in various permutations, but the option didn't change the Table of Contents output. Maybe, I am using the option wrong?

Comment: Try `make clean` then `make html`. You might have some cached objects. If that does not work, then it could be related to the theme you use. Alabaster has poor navigation support.

Comment: If this can be reproduced without .md files and MyST-parser, then I think you should post a [mcve] that uses reST and vanilla Sphinx only.

Comment: Try using `a <a/a>` and `a <a/a/a>` in the toctree entries with and without the `.md` sufix to see if that fixes the issue.